# How to say 'can' in Spanish? What is the difference between "lata" and "bote"?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, vocabulario, sinónimos

I have translated noun "can" into Spanish. There are two expressions there: *lata f*, *bote m*.

I am studying the difference between them.

[image]

- **lata**: "Envase hecho de hojalata. Una lata de tabaco, de salmón, de pimientos." or " Tabla delgada sobre la cual se aseguran las tejas." - RAE
- **bote**: "Salto que da una pelota u otro cuerpo elástico que sale despedido al chocar contra una superficie dura." or "Salto que da cualquier cuerpo elevándose desde la superficie donde se encuentra."- RAE

Hypothesis: *lata* refers to can of food, *bote* refers to garbage can.

Am I right? What is the difference?

Comment: **Bote** in this case is http://dle.rae.es/?id=5yboas9: Recipiente pequeño, comúnmente cilíndrico, que sirve para guardar tanto líquidos como objetos.  I'd say the difference is mainly in the *shape*: bote is usually cylindrical, lata is usually *non cylindrical* (like a "lata de sardinas", but with exceptions, like a "lata de cerveza")

Answer (score 8):

Relevant RAE definitions are:

- **Lata**: Envase hecho de hojalata *(can made of tin)*
- **Bote**: Recipiente pequeño, comúnmente cilíndrico, que sirve para guardar tanto líquidos como objetos. *(small can, often cylindrical, used for storing liquids and objects as well)*

So, *Lata* is a **metal** can, often used for drinks.

[image: Two "latas"]

And some food:

[image]

And **bote** is a can made of other materials. For example

[image]

[image]

Comment: A *bote* is close to a [jar](http://www.ikea.com/us/en/images/products/korken-jar-with-lid__0131001_PE285442_S4.JPG), in that it is frequently made of glass, or a [bin](http://mammothcleaningsupplies.co.uk/black-dust-bin-80-litres-w1280h1024q90i2820.jpg), in that it is frequently made of plastic, but a *bote* can also be made of metal, as in a [bote de galletas](https://cdn1.solorecetas.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/10-galletas-de-jengibre.jpg). A *lata*, on the other hand, is always made of metal.

Answer (score 3):

"Bote", "lata" and "*pote*" can be synonyms in some countries, and for adding some complications in some countries some terms are not used at all.

For example, in my country (Venezuela), the word "bote" in not used at all, "pote" is used to name almost all kinds of recipients containing any kind of liquids or arid, (eatables or not), the word "lata" is referred to any kind of recipients made of metallic materials, no matter the contents.

I believe in Central America and Mexico, the word "bote" is most used at all.

Good luck!

Comment: In spain, "pote" is not used. I will say more, i have never heard that word.

Comment: +1 for regional differeces.In Argentina "bote" is not used (only for "boat"). We use "lata" for metal recipients and "frasco" for glass.

Answer (score 0):

In the Rioplatense area (as @leonbloy wrote in a comment),

- A can is called "lata".
- Mayonnaise and jam come in a "frasco". (In *some* cases, also "pote".)
- Garbage goes into "el tacho".

Answer (score 0):

En Asturias (España) a la lata de refresco o de cerveza también la llamamos **bote**, indistintamente.

Sirvan como ejemplo un par de artículos de prensa:

- https://www.lne.es/asturias/2019/07/22/detenido-autovia-villaviciosa-drogado-ebrio-21460834.html
- https://www.elcomercio.es/20100426/asturias/gijon/detenido-hombre-intento-agredir-201004261538.html